# How to wire two light bulb sockets inside a ceiling fixture?

Tags: electrical, wiring, ceiling, light-fixture

I purchased a flush-mount ceiling light with 2 light bulbs.  The wiring is a simple 1 black, 1 white, and 1 ground to the ceiling box, but there were also wires connecting one bulb to the other.  During installation, I mistakenly pulled on the wires connecting the two light sockets.  I looked at the bases to the two light bulbs and there is no place for the bent wires to connect to the other socket (Should there be a screw?).

What do I do to fix the light fixture before installing it to the ceiling box?  Do I need to purchase a new light socket with attachments for holding the wires from the other light socket?

Answer (score 3):

If you pulled the wire from the socket then the best way to repair this is to replace the socket unless it happens to have screw terminals on it (I doubt it).  If you mistakenly removed a wire nut then you can easily correct this.  Wire all black wires together, all whites together, and the grounds together with wire nuts (often they are supplied with the fixture).

The lights should be wired in parallel (white-to-white, etc.), not series.  Do not wire black-to-white and black-to-white.

If you are unsure of how to make this repair then the safest thing to do is replace the fixture and/or consult an electrician.

Answer (score 1):

There should be two wires running to the back or side of each light socket. If you have pulled one out, you will probably only find the screw behind the fitting (so you may have to screw the fitting off)

is your setup anything like this photo?

[image]

As you can see. the connections are done in parallel. if there is a third wire ( normally green and yellow. then you have removed the earth wire ( which will need to be connected to an earth point on the casing and an earth point on the fixture)

The setup shown on [this](http://www.hometips.com/how-it-works/lamp-wiring-diagram.html) link, demonstrates how the connection points may be covered by the outer shell of the fixture.